# XSLT Transformation create a soap fault

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to create a xslt which transforms the response message to a soap fault.
I tried creating the xslt but the result is not as expected.Attached the Input,Expected Output,xslt and Result after xslt transformation. Can you please help.

Input:

```
 <response>
                    <metadata>
                    </metadata>
                    <message-body>
                        <errors>
                            <transaction-id>12345</transaction-id>
                            <claim-id>124545454</claim-id>
                            <suffix-id>545454</suffix-id>
                            <messages>
                                <message-id>123</message-id>
                                <message-type>E</message-type>
                                <message-description>Claim not found</message-description>
                            </messages>
                            <messages>
                                <message-id>256</message-id>
                                <message-type>M</message-type>
                                <message-description>Username not valid</message-description>
                            </messages>
                        </errors>
                    </message-body>
  </response>
```

Expected output:

```
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                        <soap:Header />
                        <soap:Body>
                            <soap:Fault>
                                <soap:Code>
                                    <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
                                </soap:Code>
                                <soap:Detail>
                                        <soap:Text  xml:lang="en">[E]100000:UserId Not Found;[M]100001:Source System Not Found</soap:Text>
                                </soap:Detail>
                            </soap:Fault>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>
```

XSLT:

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:output  method="text"/>
         <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
          <xsl:template match="/">
                  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                    <soap:Header />
                    <soap:Body>
                        <soap:Fault>
                            <soap:Code>
                                <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
                            </soap:Code>
                            <soap:Detail>
                                    <soap:Text  xml:lang="en"><xsl:apply-templates/></soap:Text>
                            </soap:Detail>
                        </soap:Fault>
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="messages[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="messages/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(';', 1, position() > 1)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring('[', 1, name()='message-id')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(']', 1, name()='message-id')"/>
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
             <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
             </soap:Code>
             <soap:Detail>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">12345124545454545454[123];E;Claim not found,[256];M;Username not valid</soap:Text>
             </soap:Detail>
          </soap:Fault>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Help Appreciated

Comment: You have just destroyed my formatting work on your post. Really. Pay some attention to how the editor works. It's not that hard to create a properly formatted post.

Comment: Hi Tomalak,Apologies I was doing the formatting,i did not notice your comments.

Comment: The editor tells you when somebody else has edited your post, so it can't be that you didn't notice. For next time: Please look before you overwrite edits. Anyway, now that the formatting is okay, I have no more objections.

Comment: There are many solutions to your questions so far. Please note, you can and have to accept questions! See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Be a part of the community and follow the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. wrong matching**:

Following piece of code is wrong:

```
<soap:Detail>
    <soap:Text  xml:lang="en"><xsl:apply-templates/></soap:Text>
</soap:Detail>
```

Your context-node is "/", so your document node. You will process the entire input-xml (as long as there isn't a matching template, which will NOT process any further childs). With the background knowledge, xslt got a **default copy-text-to-output** technique, you get the wrong content into your element.

Suggested change:

```
<soap:Detail>
  <soap:Text  xml:lang="en"><xsl:apply-templates select="/response/message-body/errors/messages"/></soap:Text>
</soap:Detail>
```

**II. wrong output-method:**

```
<xsl:output  method="text"/>
```

will only output text-strings. Change the method to `xml`.